# "Zombie" file in ntfs drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

In my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, I have an NTFS partition as main file storage, along with the Ubuntu partition and a third one with Windows 10. In the NTFS partition I have a file I cannot delete, rename or `chown`, although I can modify the contents of the file.

`ls -la` of the file:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     5 mar  5 12:06 'the file'
```

fstab entry of the NTFS partition (mounted at startup)

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/64DBF6E943285BF9 /media/user/the_drive auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

How can I delete it?

Comment: Show all characters of the filename -- there could be some odd ones causing the issue. Also, try creating a new folder, moving the file to the folder, and remove the folder with `rm -r`, i.e.,recursively.